# Cannot complete code (sugget code) jsp in apache netbeans 13

Tags: jsp, autosuggest, netbeans-13

I cannot automatically complete (suggest code) code JSP in Apache Netbeans 13, although I can use it in netbeans 8.2. How can I fix it?
[image: No suggestions]